# Sphinx: too many string attributes

Tags: sphinx

when indexing writes error:
too many string attributes (current index format allows up to 4 GB). 
how to fix this problem
db on 80 mln rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use less attributes, or split you index into parts.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some examples and links with your answer. I would be very grateful.